# How to prevent non registered users to load web pages for registered users?

Tags: php, html, database

I'm building a website for didactic purpose. I have some .htm page accessible from all user and other pages accessible only for registered user with a database (username and passowrd).

My professor wants that I don't generate web pages with php, but I must have the .htm files for web pages.

For example for homepage I have "homepage.htm" and "hompage_logged.htm".

How can I prevent an unregistred user lo load a page for registered user if he knows the URL?

Comment: You change your html pages to php scripts that check if the user is logged in.

Comment: But in this way I have to rename the .htm web pages in .php?

Comment: Yes they do. You can use 'raw' HTML in PHP scripts. Is there a reason you don't want to change them to PHP scripts?

Comment: yes, my teacher wants that i have .htm file. So is this not possible? What do you mean for raw html?

Comment: You could technically use cookies to keep track of users. Though, cookies are extremely unreliable.

Comment: is there some reasonable reason your professor insists on only .htm extensions on webpage files? .php is a perfectly valid webpage extension

Comment: i cannot put a php script in a page .htm? What do you mean for raw html?

Comment: He could use a javascript controller to manage things and ajax load in page content.

Comment: Meaning you just rename your files from .html to .php, and they still work exactly the same way as they did previously. Then you just add a small amount of PHP to the top of your files to check if a user is logged in.

Comment: so, taking apart what i have misunderstood, what's the best practice ? I'm thinking to do what you say: rename the .html pages in .php and add a session control. Where i have to put this control? before the raw page or inside the head or somewhere else? Thaks all!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) variables for the user once they are logged in. Once you have done that you will add a php script similar to this,

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   echo "<html> Your html here </html>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I already read about this possibility but my main request was to don't have .php web pages but .htm.

Comment: The standard structure for a user login utilizes php and mySQL. There are other ways of doing this, however none of which are built solely on html. You must at some point use a server-side language, hence the implementation of php.

Comment: I think i will shot for this solution, thanks! P.S. I already used php for storing account data and for login. Today is the second day of php for me :) (the first coding)